# How to alarm set schedule time?

Tags: android

This code working fine but i want to schedule time.I got a value from web service particular time . I have to passed time in array for alarm set. but it's not working .Only one time passed means it's working perfectly.Please give me solution .I want to pass it array value to alarm manager.

```
    private void setAlarm(Calendar calSet) {
        int hours = calSet.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int mnts = calSet.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int ampm = calSet.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

        String str = "AM";
        if (ampm == 0) {
            str = "AM";
        } else {
            str = "PM";
        }
        int i = 0;


        String time = hours + " : " + mnts + " : " + str;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION_NAME);
        // Set the Alarm ID as extra data to be displayed in the popup
        alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmID", m_alarmId);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmTime", time);

        // Create the corresponding PendingIntent object
        PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, m_alarmId,
                alarmIntent, 0);

        // Register the alarm with the alarm manager
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
                alarmPI);

    }
```

**AlarmServiceReceiverClass**

```
public class AlarmServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // The alarm action defined in AndroidManifest.xml
    private static final String ALARM_ACTION_NAME = "com.goodmor.broadcast.ALARM";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Toast.makeText(context , "Alarm received!",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Handle the alarm broadcast
        Log.i(this.toString(), "111111111111");
        if (ALARM_ACTION_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // Launch the alarm popup dialog
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            alarmIntent.setClass(context, AndroidAlarmService.class);
            alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // Pass on the alarm ID as extra data
            alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmID", intent.getIntExtra("AlarmID", -1));
            alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmTime",
                    intent.getStringExtra("AlarmTime"));
            // Start the popup activity
            context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the m_alarmId if you are going to add add another alarm, if you are not changing the m_alarmId, the previous alarm will be replaced for new alarm, previous alarm wont invoke

```
  PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, **m_alarmId**,
            alarmIntent, 0);
```

Comment: m_alarmId value set zero.when i was click that time i was increment value ++ karthick.

Comment: Yeah that's right, its working or not ?? can you post your setalarm method now?

Comment: k but above i have mention set alarm code .Please see that karthick

Comment: no karthik .If i am static value passed but eventhough it's not working String items = "0 : 18 : PM";

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Edited        
    int m_alarmId=0;

    private void setAlarm(Calendar calSet) {
    int hours = calSet.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int mnts = calSet.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int ampm = calSet.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

    String str = "AM";
    if (ampm == 0) {
        str = "AM";
    } else {
        str = "PM";
    }
    int i = 0;

    //Edited 
    m_alarmId++;



    String time = hours + " : " + mnts + " : " + str;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION_NAME);
    // Set the Alarm ID as extra data to be displayed in the popup
    alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmID", m_alarmId);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmTime", time);

    // Create the corresponding PendingIntent object
    PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, m_alarmId,
            alarmIntent, 0);

    // Register the alarm with the alarm manager
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
            alarmPI);

}
```

and here you are passing the alarm id to AlarmReceiver Class right? then in the AlarmReceiver class pass this alarm id, if cant get it please post your AlarmReceiver class

Here you are passing the m_alarmId to AlarmReceiver class,

```
  alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmID", m_alarmId);
```

Comment: Please see above this coding i have mention AlarmServiceReceiverClass